# is there a way to check if there is an approval process to aply to a record from a visual flow?

Tags: approval-process, visual-flows

I'm doing a visual flow to validate some information before calling an approval process, in some cases the record  does not apply to any approval process and I get an error. Is there a way to know if the record aply to the approval process before call it?

Thanks!